# Warning: File listed in ass.cabal file does not exist: README.md

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've just started to learn haskell and I faced this proble while trying to         **stack build**.
What's the way to solve it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can also delete the section about readme in your cabal file

Comment: I have created a PR to fix that warning: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/pull/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `README.md` in your project. Just create that file and the warning will go off:

```
$ touch README.md
```

Note that you have to create the file inside the project's folder.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Sibi.

Comment: But i have to use Windows

Comment: @arturdinanmitt Does this work on Windows: `copy NUL README.md` ?

Comment: Yes, it's work. But it cause this:
Linking .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\pro-exe\pro-exe.exe ...
C:/Users/artur_1sf4rbk/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/x86_64-windows/ghc-8.0.2/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSpro-0.1.0.0-AZbCCAnOhQfJaZyKTc2UJL
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

Comment: And have I always create REDME for myself?

Comment: For the linker error please create a new question. Do not forget to include the cabal file and your stack.yaml

Comment: @arturdinanmitt No, only once. Also as epsilonhalbe suggested, you can remove the entry from the cabal section.

Comment: A default README should be there if you use `stack new`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can remove the file from your sources by deleting its name from `package.yaml`

```yaml
extra-source-files:
- README.md  # <-- delete
- CHANGELOG.md
```